# I am new to test ng and facing null pointer exception during execution of second annotation. First annotation is working fine

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My code:

```
public class NewTest {
    public static WebDriver driver; 

@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun=true)
public void intiate() {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
          String Appurl= "http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/";
          driver. manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
          driver.navigate().to(Appurl);

      } 


  @Test  (alwaysRun=true)
  public void Enterusernamedetails() {  
/*    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      String Appurl= "http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/";
      driver. manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
      driver.navigate().to(Appurl);*/

      WebElement UsrName = driver.findElement(By.name("firstname"));
      if(UsrName!=null)
      {
          UsrName.sendKeys("Hemamalini");
          System.out.println("First name has been entered");
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("First name element is not visible");
      }


  WebElement lastName = driver.findElement(By.name("lastname"));
  if(lastName!=null)
  {
      lastName.sendKeys("K");
      System.out.println("Last name has been entered");
  }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("Last name element is not visible");
  }

  WebElement radbtnSex = driver.findElement(By.id("sex-0"));
  if(radbtnSex!=null)
  {
      radbtnSex.click();
      System.out.println("Sex radio button has been clicked");
  }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("Sex radio button element is not been clicked");
  }

  WebElement radbtnExper = driver.findElement(By.id("exp-2"));
  if(radbtnExper!=null)
  {
      radbtnExper.click();
      System.out.println("Experience radio button has been clicked");
  }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("Experience radio button element is not been clicked");
  }

  WebElement txtDatePicker = driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker"));
  if(txtDatePicker!=null)   
  {
      txtDatePicker.sendKeys("10/11/2017");
      System.out.println("Date has been entered");
  }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("Date element is not visible");
  }

  WebElement chkbox = driver.findElement(By.id("profession-1"));
  if(chkbox!=null)
  {
      chkbox.click();
      System.out.println("Profession checkbox has been clicked");
  }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("Profession checkbox element is not been clicked");
  }

  WebElement chkboxtool = driver.findElement(By.id("tool-2"));
  if(chkboxtool!=null)
  {
      chkboxtool.click();
      System.out.println("Automation tool checkbox has been clicked");
  }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("Automation tool element is not been clicked");
  }

  Select drpContinents = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("continents")));
  if(drpContinents!=null)
  {
      drpContinents.selectByVisibleText("Australia");
      System.out.println("Automation tool checkbox has been clicked");

  }

  Select drpCommands = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selenium_commands")));
  if(drpCommands!=null)
  {
      drpCommands.selectByVisibleText("Switch Commands");
      System.out.println("command has been clicked");
  }

      WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("submit"));
      if(button!=null)
      {
          button.click();
          System.out.println("button has been clicked");
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("button element is not been clicked");
      }

      WebElement uploadfile = driver.findElement(By.id("photo"));
      if(uploadfile!=null)
      {
          uploadfile.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\391387.CTS\\Documents\\New folder\\Spritz_Selenium_Grid_Setup_v 2 0.docx");
          System.out.println("document has been uploaded");
      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println("button document has not been uploaded");
      }

      driver.quit();
  }

}
```

Comment: Add your exception and on which line it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you have initiated `WebDriver driver` multiple times.

1. `public static WebDriver driver;`
2. In `@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun=true)` see `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`
3. In `@Test  (alwaysRun=true)` see `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

> Here you have initiate driver 3 times and As per `TestNG`,  `@BeforeSuites` run first. Change your code as under :

1. `public static WebDriver driver = null;`
2. In `@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun=true)` : Replace below code with `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

   ```
   //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // Old line
   driver = new ChromeDriver(); // new line
   ```
3. In `@Test  (alwaysRun=true)` : Comment/remove below code

   ```
   //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",  "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
   //driver = new ChromeDriver();
   ```

Hope you understand it is **Basic Java Code error**. Let me know If you require more help.

Answer (score 0):

In our project we are using separate class to choose driver for
 our test, you can try this:

```
public class SetupBrowser {

public static WebDriver SetupDriver(String browser) {
    WebDriver driver = null;
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("FF")) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilitiesFF = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capabilitiesFF.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.MARIONETTE, true);
            //capabilitiesFF.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, true);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilitiesFF);

    }
    else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");

        // Setting IE to clean session
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);

        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

    }
    else {
           driver = new ChromeDriver();
           //////////
               }
    return driver;
}
```

We read type of browser from properties file.

---

Call/Write code whenever you require to open browser :

```
SetupBrowser.SetupDriver("FF");
```